# How can I visualize insight in 2 predictors from a NN for a specific range of a third predictor

Tags: r

I have fitted a neuralnet based on 3 variables: x1, x2, x3 generating predictions y.
I would like to construct a matrix based on x1, x3 and the average prediction y for each combination while x2 is within range 0-25. (next I would like to make a similar matrix for x2 in range 26-50, 51-75 and 76-100.

I have made many attempts with dplyr and solutions based on pivottables in R although I do not succeed.

Currently I have the code below:

```
library(nnet)
library(caret)
library(dplyr)

x <- mydata[,2:4]
y <- mydata[,5]

parti <- createDataPartition(y, times = 1, p=0.8, list = FALSE)

x_train <- x[parti,]
x_test <- x[-parti,]
y_train <- y[parti]
y_test <- y[-parti]

fit <- nnet(y_train~., x_train, size=12, maxit=500, linout=T, decay=0.01)

x1 <- seq(0,100,10)
x2 <- seq(0,100,10)
x3 <- seq(0,100,10)

my_grid <- expand.grid(x1=x1, x2=x2, x3=x3) 

predictions <- predict(fit ,my_grid, type="raw")
testResults <- data.frame(my_grid, y = predictions)

plot(testResults)

myMatrix <- testResults  %>% filter(x2>0 & x2<25) %>% group_by(x1) %>% group_by(x3) %>% summarize(y=average(y))
```

This code generates the folowing table:

```
A tibble: 11 x 2
         x3      y
      <dbl>    <dbl>
 1        0  18.5   
 2       10 -19.2   
 3       20  -2.93  
 4       30  10.4   
 5       40  10.9   
 6       50   4.42  
 7       60   0.511 
 8       70   0.0232
 9       80  -3.67  
10       90  -7.26  
11      100  -8.37
```

Although the outcome I am looking for is something like

```
            x3 ->      
         x1     0    10   30   40  50  60  70  80  90  100
 1        0  18.5   12    7    5 
 2       10 -19.2   1     3    2
 3       20  -2.93  22    1    etc
 4       30  10.4   3     7
 5       40  10.9   4     3
 6       50   4.42  5     2
 7       60   0.511 3     1
 8       70   0.02324     9
 9       80  -3.67  5     2
10       90  -7.26  5     5
11      100  -8.37  -1    0
```

Based on this matrix I would like to generate a heatmap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
vb = testResults[testResults$x2 > 0 & testResults$x2 <= 25,]
vb = dcast(vb,  x1~x3, value.var=y, fun.aggregate=mean)
```